# How would you make a terminal inside SDL?

Tags: shell, terminal, sdl

So, I want to make a terminal "window" inside an SDL app, but there's not too much info on how to approach it, is there a lib o a naive way of doing it?

Comment: What do you mean, drawing letters in an SDL window to make it look like a terminal? Or opening a regular terminal alongside an SDL window?

Comment: I want to make a lil terminal inside the desktop app

Comment: Like if you were to make a game with a real terminal inside, it's not the main feature but it's functional.

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're stuck on? Start by making an array of strings, and drawing them inside of a black rectangle, or something like that...

Comment: I don't want to make a fake terminal for linux, I want a real fully-integrated terminal, like if I was to make a app with a terminal in it.

Comment: Then don't draw the black rectangle with letters over the entire window, and put it where you need it to be?

Comment: Well, that could work, but how would you do that?